# codeignite how to echo fetched values in model page inside function

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and I'd like to test a condition in my models page using info fetched from mysql table.

**My question is**,  how to I echo the total number of values fetched from the "reviews" mysql table. The results is 3 - all data found in the

**Here my code** in the model page

```
$query = "
    SELECT 3 - COUNT(*) AS value FROM `reviews`
    INNER JOIN users ON user_id = users.uid

    WHERE value = 1 AND user_id = '" . $logged_in_user_via_session . "'
";


$query = $this->db->query($query);

// how to I echo the total number of values fetched from the "reviews" mysql table.
// so I basically want to know if the result is 0 or 1 or 2 so i can continue with additional conditions
```

Thanks in advance

**Final Clean Answer**

The ticked answer is though out well, as well as all the other answers. However, codeigniter does allow you to add Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result to numbers as show in **$records->num_rows() -3 ;**. Its recommended to add it to a variable after records as shown below

```
$query = "
                    SELECT COUNT(*) AS value FROM `reviews`
                    INNER JOIN users ON user_id = users.uid

                    WHERE value = 1 AND user_id = '" . $logged_in_user_via_session . "'
                    ";

                    $records = $this->db->query($query);

                    $countedRows=$records->num_rows();
                    $countedRows;
                    // subtracting three (3)
                    $total_minus_three = $countedRows - 3;

                    echo $total_minus_three;
```

Comment: What you mean by `3 -` into query

Comment: well, I'd like to count all records and subtract them from three

Comment: But you can also subtract after fetch record. check your query is working into mysql server and what result it will return.

Comment: Do you mind showing me an example please? Do I just deduct it from the total record?

Comment: As per my view, remove 3- from query and get actual result and check it, is it proper result or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS value FROM `reviews`
    INNER JOIN users ON user_id = users.uid

    WHERE value = 1 AND user_id = '" . $logged_in_user_via_session . "'
";

$records = $this->db->query($query);

echo "Total Records ->".$records->num_rows();

to print all records use print_r($records->row_array());
```

**EDIT**

As I see your comments you want to subtract 3 from your result.

```
echo '-3 result is ->'. $records->num_rows() -3 ;
```

Comment: Thanks, But I am getting this error for the echo total record line ""  Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to string""

Comment: Thanks @404 Brain Not Found this is works fine!! :). As Mayank Vadiya recommended, its better to subtract three from the total outside the query as opposed to inside. I just thought if its inside, the query, it will be better practice

Answer (score 1):

You should try like this way

```
$query = "
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS value FROM `reviews`
    INNER JOIN users ON user_id = users.uid

    WHERE value = 1 AND user_id = '" . $logged_in_user_via_session . "'
";

$records = $this->db->query($query);

$countedRows=$records->num_rows();
echo "Total number".$countedRows;
echo "What you want is".$countedRows-3;
```

Comment: thanks, we're all taken your adivse and we've put the subtraction outside the query. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can find total number of records by using this command.

```
$query = "
    SELECT 3 - COUNT(*) AS value FROM `reviews`
    INNER JOIN users ON user_id = users.uid

    WHERE value = 1 AND user_id = '" . $logged_in_user_via_session . "'
";

   echo $query->num_rows(); // for total record
```

or

```
$this->db->from("table name")->count_all_results()
```

or

```
echo "Total Records ->".$records->row_array();
```

Comment: Thanks @Manvendra Rajpurohit I just tired what you recommended, but I keep getting "1". I have more than 10 results in the table. Any ideas? thanks

Comment: sorry but I did'n copy your code. its just a co-incident. If you seem i copied your code then i am sorry for this